# ClassNotFoundException while dynamic class loading in JBoss 7.1.1 from OSGi-bundle

Tags: jboss, classpath, osgi, classnotfoundexception, dynamic-class-loaders

I deployed a simple OSGi test-bundle into JBoss 7.1.1 and try to dynamically instantiate the Jacorb ORB by doing

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("org.jacorb.orb.ORB");
```

All I got is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB from [Module "deployment.test:1.0.0" from Service Module Loader]
```

What I already did:

- in the JBoss configuration `standalone.xml` I added for the osgi-subsystem the capability `<capability name="org.jacorb" startlevel="1"/>`, so that the `org.jacorb` module is loaded. That already solved the problem, that the installation of my test bundle fails.
- I declared the `Dependencies`-Descriptor on `org.jacorb` in my `MANIFEST.MF` (also tried with and without the `export` option): `Dependencies: org.jacorb export`
- I added the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to my `META-INF` with the following content

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
         <dependencies>
           <module name="org.jacorb" />
         </dependencies>
       </deployment>
     </jboss-deployment-structure>

Also I did experiments with the ClassLoaders and realized, that the ContextClassLoader is `null`. But in the end, I cannot effect this as the non-test-code, because the `Class.forName()` cannot be changed to use a specific classloader.

So why do I get this ClassNotFoundException?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 1):

After hours of digging I did the puzzle ;-)

1. In `standalone.xml/domain.xml` JBoss configuration I added `<capability name="org.jacorb" startlevel="1"/>` in the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">` section under `<capabilities>`
2. In the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` I added `DynamicImport-Package: org.jacorb.orb` to allow the classloader to dynamically extend the classpath during runtime
3. Set the context classloader by `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()` that has been `null` before

Comment: did you try `Import-Package: org.jacorb.org` or `Import-Package: org.jacorb.org;resolution=optional` ? Those are recommended ways, DynamicImport-Package is not. Also, Class.forName() *does* have an optional parameter for the classloader.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a normal OSGi bundle and it should see the org.jacorb.orb.ORB class, 
then you should have:
1. ALL org.jacorb packages and subpackages have to be exported in the osgi framework. 
2. Your bundle has to import ALL of the packages you use - e.g. with 
"Import-Package:org.jacorb.orb"
Check that the versions are compatible.
Check that you import all packages and subpackages. Import of org.jacorb doesn't imply org.jacorb.orb.

If both conditions are satisfied, then the Bundle Classloader of your bundle should be able to see org.jacorb.orb.ORB.